# I Am Not Getting the Result I Expect Using readLine() in Java

Tags: java, java-io

I am using the code snippet below, however it's not working quite as I understand it should.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String line;
    try {
        line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

From reading the Javadoc about `readLine()` it says:

Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed (`\n`), a carriage return (`\r`), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

**Returns**:
A `String` containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

**Throws**: 
`IOException` - If an I/O error occurs

From my understanding of this, `readLine` should return null the first time no input is entered other than a line termination, like `\r`. However, this code just ends up looping infinitely. After debugging, I have found that instead of null being returned when just a termination character is entered, it actually returns an empty string (""). This doesn't make sense to me. What am I not understanding correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> From my understanding of this, readLine should return null the first time no input is entered other than a line termination, like '\r'.

That is not correct. `readLine` will return `null` if the end of the stream is reached. That is, for example, if you are reading a file, and the file ends, or if you're reading from a socket and the socket closses.

But if you're simply reading the console input, hitting the return key on your keyboard does not constitute an end of stream. It's simply a character that is returned (`\n` or `\r\n` depending on your OS).

So, if you want to break on both the empty string and the end of line, you should do:

```
while (line != null && !line.equals(""))
```

Also, your current program should work as expected if you pipe some file directly into it, like so:

```
java -cp . Echo < test.txt
```

Comment: Does readLine() return the line plus the line feed charater-'\n' or just the line?

Comment: From JavaDoc: "A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached".

Answer (score 3):

No input is not the same as the end of the stream. You can usually simulate the end of the stream in a console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (AFAIK some systems use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> instead). But I guess this is not what you want so better test for empty strings additionally to null strings.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library which has a good api for common :) actions. You could use statically import StringUtils and use its method isNotEmpty(String ) to get:

```
while(isNotEmpty(line)) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

It might be useful someday:) There are also other useful classes in this lib.